# How do I keep elements within their area when the browser resizes?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the browser (shrink all the way) the four boxes will break out of the pink background and make the whole layout very messy. What do I do so that when I shrink the browser, they will stay within the pink background? I would like to boxes to wrap on top each of other without doing `flex-growth` or `flex basis`.

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 650px;
  }
  
  header {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: blue;
  }
  
  aside {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
    background: green;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  
  main {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    background: pink;
  }
  
  footer {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    background: yellow;
  }

  .container{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

  .box{
    border: 2px red solid;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box1 box"></div>
        <div class="box2 box"></div>
        <div class="box3 box"></div>
        <div class="box4 box"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using px or rems try using ems or %. These are relative to their parent element so they will stay inside the box. Px and rems are relative to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You used `fixed-wrap` on the `container`, so you need to give their children the property:

```
.container>div{
    flex: 0 50%;
}
```

(I put 50% since you want 2 boxes in a row, if you want 3, put 33%, etc...)

Then give `container` the property: `height: 100%;`

Finally, I added `box-sizing: border-box;` so the border will be inside the div and not outer border (so the whole size of it will not change).

Full snippet:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 650px;
  }
  
  header {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: blue;
  }
  
  aside {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
    background: green;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  
  main {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    background: pink;
  }
  
  footer {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    background: yellow;
  }

  .container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;
}

  .container>div{
    flex: 0 50%;
}

  .box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px red solid;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box1 box"></div>
        <div class="box2 box"></div>
        <div class="box3 box"></div>
        <div class="box4 box"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
```